# Atualizar table após inserir dado no banco AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um modal com um `form`, preencho esse `form` e clico no botão salvar e os dados são salvos no banco, porém tenho que dar um `F5` pra atualizar a tabela. Como posso atualizar a tabela depois de inserir esses dados?

Atualmente é dessa forma que carrego os dados vindos da API:

```
$scope.colaboradores = colaboradores.data;
```

Controller completo:

```
angular.module("oraculo").controller("colaboradorController", function($scope, $routeParams, $location, colaboradores, colaboradorAPI){

    $scope.colaboradores = colaboradores.data;

    $scope.adicionarColaborador = function(colaborador){
        colaboradorAPI.saveColaborador(colaborador).success(function(data){
            console.log("Salvar!");
            $scope.colaboradores = colaboradores.data;
            delete $scope.colaborador;
            $scope.colaboradorForm.$setPristine();
        })
        .error(function(response, status){
            console.log("erro "+status);
        });
    }

});
```

Configuração da Rota:

```
angular.module("oraculo").config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        templateUrl: "public/views/colaborador.html",
        controller: "colaboradorController",
        resolve: {
            colaboradores: function(colaboradorAPI){
                return colaboradorAPI.getColaboradores();
            }
        }
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: "/home"});

});
```

Já tentei colocar um `$scope.colaboradores = colaboradores.data;` no método `adicionarColaborador` porém não funcionou.

Botão Salvar que fica dentro do modal:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="adicionarColaborador(colaborador)" ng-disabled="colaboradorForm.$invalid" data-dismiss="modal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    Salvar
</button>
```

Comment: Tente dar um $scope.$apply() após $scope.colaboradores = colaboradores.data;

Comment: Quanto tento dar um `$scope.$apply();` da esse erro: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`

Comment: Remova o  delete $scope.colaborador;

Comment: Continua o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No teu código ao invés de:

> $scope.colaboradores = colaboradores.data

altere para:

> $scope.colaboradores.push(colaborador)

Observe que você está setando o valor incial para $scope.colaboradores após salvar um novo colaborador. O correto seria incluir o novo colaborador na lista já existente.

Comment: Dessa forma funciona, porém a tabela não é preenchida corretamente, ou seja, a linha que mostra na table não é a linha retornada do banco.

Comment: Então mude para $scope.colaboradores.push(data), verifique se a data é o colaborador que foi inserido. Precisa ver o que teu server retorna

Comment: agora após clicar no botão salvar não aparece nada na table

Comment: O que vem na variável data?

Comment: essa data vem do `resolve`

Comment: Se não der certo usando `resolve` eu faço da maneira simples, que é passar o resultado da função que faz o GET pra uma variável e chama-la assim que a função que salva os dados for chamada

Comment: @EmirMarques A sua resposta daria certo caso o retorno fosse um array e ele estivesse iterando o array e dando push posição por posição, caso fosse um array isso não iria aparecer da forma esperada.

Techies qual o html que está sendo responsável por estar renderizando os dados e qual o retorno do servidor ?

Comment: Chamando a colaboradorAPI.getColaboradores() não resolve?

Comment: Corrigindo meu comentário:

@EmirMarques A sua resposta daria certo caso o retorno fosse um registro.

 Techies qual o html que está sendo responsável por estar renderizando os dados e qual o retorno do servidor ?

Comment: @FelippeTadeu não entendi, o item que pedi para ele dar push foi justamente no colaborador que acabou de receber. O que acontece é que a forma como foi desenvolvido necessita uma outra consulta que retorne todos os itens da lista, nesse caso o colaboradorAPI.getColaboradores()

Comment: @FelippeTadeu é a página colaborador.html. O servidor retorna um OK e o dado é inserido no banco, porém tenho que dar um F5 pra atualizar a table

Comment: @Techies vc pode dar um console.log(data) dentro do método que salva o dados e postar aqui?

Comment: Não exibe nada, fica vazio. essa data é diferente dessa `$scope.colaboradores = colaboradores.data;`

Comment: @Techies então vc pode rodar o método colaboradorAPI.getColaboradores() dentro do sucess para obter a lista nova. Vc também precisa analisar se a tua API retorna o dado persistido no banco

Comment: Sim, dessa forma eu consigo carregar as tabelas. Eu apenas estava buscando uma solução alternativa

Comment: Então, entendo, existem formas alternativas mais tudo depende do retorno da tua API, vc consegue confirmar se ela retornar o objeto serealizado?

Comment: Sim, está retornando, a dificuldade é apenas carregar os dados quando utilizo o `resolve` na configuração da Rota, mas enfim. Vou utilizar da forma simples mesmo.